# Hazelcast Management Center is not able to connect one of clusters

Tags: hazelcast

Hazelcast Management Center is not able to connect one of clusters. Attached is the image for the same.
I am new to hazelcast and trying to monitor the clusters created on different environments. [image]

```
 hazelcast:  
  network:  
    join:  
      multicast:  
        enabled: false  
      aws:  
        enabled: true  
        tag-key: HazelcastClusterName  
        tag-value: my-cluster  
    rest-api:  
      enabled: true  
      endpoint-groups:  
        CLUSTER_READ:  
          enabled: true  
        CLUSTER_WRITE:  
          enabled: false  
        HEALTH_CHECK:  
          enabled: true  
        HOT_RESTART:  
          enabled: false  
        WAN:  
          enabled: false  
        DATA:  
          enabled: false  
  map:  
    default:  
      backup-count: 1  
      time-to-live-seconds: 36000  
      max-idle-seconds: 1800
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are there any logs from the Management Center you can share ? It's probably a connectivity issue

Comment: Could you also share your configuration and the versions you use?

Comment: There are no error logs in the console.. @NeilStevenson

Comment: @RafałLeszko - added config in the post.

Comment: I think the same as @Neil that it's related to the connectivity. Are you able to access your Hazelcast cluster using Hazelcast client?

Comment: Yes i am able to access it using the hazelcast client

Comment: @Priyanka you should be able to upload the same client config file to MC while you're adding a new cluster. Could you please add your client config to the question as well and comment on whether you upload a client config file to Management Center or configure it directly by configuring IP addresses via the form on the UI?

Comment: @emre I actually tried both the ways, i.e. by uploading the config file and by IP address. But none of them seems to be working.

Comment: @Priyanka could you share the client config file you tried with?

Comment: @emre same configuration is used in client config as well

Comment: @Priyanka can you please configure global logging level of MC to INFO and share the logs with us? You can start MC with `-Dhazelcast.mc.log.level=INFO` to achieve this. By default, the client in MC is set to log in level error. It might be the case that the client is logging connection problems as warning. If we confirm that this is the case, I will make sure to change the logging level of it to WARN in the next release.

Comment: I have tried this @emr but no error message is getting printed on the console